# Bind image from service in angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular5, angular6

I have an endpoint that provides me an image based on certain parameter. It's not an image url, its a plain image. So when i hit the endpoint in postman, in response, i receive an image (JPG).

I do i receive this image in a variable and bind it in  tag of HTML?

All the questions have solution for mapping an image url to image, whereas mine is an image which i have to display in UI.

**show-image-component.ts**

```
this.appservice.getImage().subscribe((image) => {
    console.log(image);
 }
)
```

**service.ts**

```
getImg() {

 return this.httpClient.get('xyz.com', {headers: this.httpHeaders});

 }
```

How should i display the image i receive in image variable on HTML?

Comment: What have you tried? My guess is you'd need to map the response to a data URI to use as the image source in HTML.

Comment: I take it you can't just use the URL as the image tag's `src`?

Answer (score 2):

You can find detailed steps on how to achieve this in this blog post -> https://blog.mikehodnick.com/angular-download-image-blob-and-bind-to-img/

TL;DR - The long and short of it is you need to do the following:

(Please note this was implemented using **Angular 4.1.3**)

1. Get your image using http
2. Set the response type to be **BLOB** so that we get the image in binary format
3. Sanitize the blob response
4. Assign the sanitized response to a member variable in your `service.ts` file
5. Assign the member variable to the `src` attribute in your view in HTML
6. Profit :D

**Sample Code from the above-linked blog post:**

**view**

```
<img [src]="imageData">
```

**component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  imageData: any;

  constructor(private http: Http, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const imageUrl = 'http://where.your.images/are/hosted.jpg';

    this.http.get(imageUrl, {
      responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob
    })
      .toPromise()
      .then((res: any) => {
        let blob = new Blob([res._body], {
          type: res.headers.get("Content-Type")
        });

        let urlCreator = window.URL;
        this.imageData = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(
            urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob));
      });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Angular 6+ you could try this

On the service:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

...

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
}

getFile(url: string): any {

  return this.http.get(url, {
    responseType: 'blob'
  })
  .pipe(
    map((res: any) => {
      const urlCreator = window.URL;
      return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(urlCreator.createObjectURL(res));
    })
 );
}
```

On the component:

```
const imgSrc: any;

downloadFile(uri) {
  this.service.getFile(uri).subscribe((res: any) => {
  this.imgSrc = res;
});
```

}

On the template:

```
<img id="myImg" [src]="imgSrc" alt="Attached file" style="width: 100%">
<button type="button" (click)="downloadFile('YourFile/Url')" id="imgBtn">
```